# Get a list of all checkboxes which are selected in a razor component

Tags: razor, blazor

I feel like I am close. I have a service that provides a list of objects. Those object in turn become a series of checkboxes. Some of the objects have children objects of the same type(recurses all the way down until no children).
Ultimately whichever boxes are checked, I will need a list of to send to another service or form or whatever.

Below is my YourComponent.razor and RecursiveExpandableWithCheckbox.razor. I've tried a few things but am unsure how to proceed.

```
<!-- YourComponent.razor -->
@page "/yourcomponent"

<div style="margin-left: 20px;">
    @foreach (var item in RootItems2())
    {
        <RecursiveExpandableWithCheckbox Title="@item.Title" ChildItems="@item.ChildItems" />
    }
</div>

@code {
    
    Dashboard.Utility.DashboardExtras dashboardExtras = new DashboardExtras();

    private List<ExpandableItemModel> RootItems2()
    {
        try
        {
            string theRootObjectId = dashboardExtras.GetTheRootObjectId();

            Task<List<Item>> items = dashboardExtras.GetItemChildrenByObjectId(theRootObjectId);
            
            List<ExpandableItemModel> rootItems = new List<ExpandableItemModel>();
            foreach (var i0 in items.Result)
            {
                rootItems.Add(new ExpandableItemModel
                    {
                        Title = i0.Name + " - " + i0.FQID.ObjectId,
                        ChildItems = RootItems666(i0.FQID.ObjectId.ToString())
                    });
            }
            return rootItems;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }

    private List<ExpandableItemModel> RootItems666(string s)
    {
        Task<List<Item>> items = dashboardExtras.GetItemChildrenByObjectId(s);
        List<ExpandableItemModel> rootItems = new List<ExpandableItemModel>();
        if (items.Result != null)
        {
            foreach (var i0 in items.Result)
            {
                rootItems.Add(new ExpandableItemModel
                    {
                        Title = i0.Name + " - " + i0.FQID.ObjectId,
                        ChildItems = RootItems666(i0.FQID.ObjectId.ToString())
                    });
            }
            return rootItems;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

```
<!-- RecursiveExpandableWithCheckbox.razor -->
<div>
    <span @onclick="ToggleCollapse">@GetExpandIcon()</span>
    <input type="checkbox" @bind="IsSelected" @oninput="OnCheckboxValueChanged" /> <!-- Checkbox -->
    <span>@Title</span>
</div>

@if (!IsCollapsed && ChildItems != null)
{
    <div style="margin-left: 20px;">
        @foreach (var item in ChildItems)
        {
            <RecursiveExpandableWithCheckbox Title="@item.Title" ChildItems="@item.ChildItems" @bind-IsSelected="@item.IsSelected"  />
        }
    </div>
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public string Title { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public List<ExpandableItemModel> ChildItems { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public bool IsSelected { get; set; } = false;
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<bool> IsSelectedChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> StringList { get; set; }
    

    private List<string> SelectedOnes = new List<string>();
    private bool IsCollapsed = true;

    private void ToggleCollapse()
    {
        IsCollapsed = !IsCollapsed;
    }

    private string GetExpandIcon()
    {
        return IsCollapsed ? "+" : "-";
    }

    private async Task OnCheckboxValueChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        IsSelected = (bool)e.Value;
        
        if (ChildItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in ChildItems)
            {
                item.IsSelected = IsSelected;
            }
        }

        await IsSelectedChanged.InvokeAsync(IsSelected);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the version of asp.net core do you use?And do you use blazor  server application ?

Comment: I was on 6 but recently changed it to 7 because MrC's example below was giving me an error until I changed to 7.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost certainly overcomplicated.

I've taken a liberty and refactored your code into what I think (I may be wrong!) you want.

First your `ExpandableItemModel`

```cs
public class ExpandableItemModel
{
    public string Title { get; init; }

    public bool IsSelected { get; private set; }

    public ExpandableItemModel(string title, bool expanded = false)
    {
        this.Title = title;
        this.IsSelected = expanded;
    }
    
    public void SetSelected(bool value)
    {
        // need to decide what behaviour you want on unset
        // do you unset all the children if you unset the parent?
        this.IsSelected = value;
        if (value) 
        { 
            foreach (var item in ChildItems)
                item.SetSelected(true);
        }
    }

    public List<ExpandableItemModel> ChildItems { get; private set; } = new();

    public bool HasChildren => ChildItems.Count > 0;
}
```

And `RecursiveExpandableWithCheckbox`:

Note `@bind:get="this.Item.IsSelected"` will show an error, but it's a lie: it will compile. The SDK needs fixing.

```cs
<div>
    <span @onclick="ToggleCollapse">@_expandIcon</span>
    <input type="checkbox" @bind:get="this.Item.IsSelected" @bind:set="this.OnSelectionChanged" />
    <span>@this.Item.Title</span>
</div>

@if (_expanded)
{
    <div style="margin-left: 20px;">
        @foreach (var item in this.Item.ChildItems)
        {
            <RecursiveExpandableWithCheckbox Item="item" />
        }
    </div>
}

@code {
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public ExpandableItemModel Item { get; set; } = default!;
    [CascadingParameter] private Func<ExpandableItemModel, bool, Task> SelectionUpdated { get; set; } = default!;
    private bool _isCollapsed = true;

    private bool _expanded => !_isCollapsed && Item.HasChildren;

    private void ToggleCollapse()
        => _isCollapsed = !_isCollapsed;

    private string _expandIcon => _isCollapsed ? "+" : "-";

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(this.Item);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(this.SelectionUpdated);
    }

    private async Task OnSelectionChanged(bool value)
    {
        await this.SelectionUpdated.Invoke(Item, value);
    }
}
```

And my demo page:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />
<CascadingValue Value="this.UpdateItem" IsFixed>
    @foreach (var item in _model)
    {
        <RecursiveExpandableWithCheckbox Item="item" />
    }
</CascadingValue>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    @foreach (var item in GetSelectedItems())
    {
        <pre>@item</pre>
    }
</div>

@code {
    private List<ExpandableItemModel> _model = new();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _model = GetModel();
    }

    private List<string> GetSelectedItems()
    {
        List<string> selectedItems = new();

        foreach(var item in _model)

            FlatPackModel(item, selectedItems);

        return selectedItems;
    }

    private void FlatPackModel(ExpandableItemModel model, List<string> items)
    {
        if (model.IsSelected)
            items.Add(model.Title);

        foreach (var item in model.ChildItems)
        {
            this.FlatPackModel(item, items);
        }
    }

    private Task UpdateItem(ExpandableItemModel item, bool selected)
    {
        item.SetSelected(selected);
        StateHasChanged();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public List<ExpandableItemModel> GetModel()
    {
        List<ExpandableItemModel> list = new();

        var m1 = new ExpandableItemModel("Europe");
        var m1_1 = new ExpandableItemModel("France");
        var m1_1_1 = new ExpandableItemModel("Paris");
        var m1_1_2 = new ExpandableItemModel("Bezier");
        var m1_2 = new ExpandableItemModel("Spain");
        var m1_2_1 = new ExpandableItemModel("Barcelona");
        var m1_2_2 = new ExpandableItemModel("Madrid");

        m1_1.ChildItems.Add(m1_1_1);
        m1_1.ChildItems.Add(m1_1_2);

        m1_2.ChildItems.Add(m1_2_1);
        m1_2.ChildItems.Add(m1_2_2);

        m1.ChildItems.Add(m1_1);
        m1.ChildItems.Add(m1_2);

        list.Add(m1);

        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added your code but I do not yet see the way to get a list of the selected items that I could potentially send off to another service or put in a form for an eventual action. In the code of the main page, how can I have a list of string from each ExpandableItemModel.Title?

Comment: See my updated answer.  I've changed the updating to a callback delegete into the main page.  The selected Items are in a string list.

Comment: Yes thank you. This approach works well to get the list of all checkboxes. Your code example broke the recursion that my code had(to support any number of nested lists). But I expect that today or tomorrow, I will post my changes to this post for a fully functioning example.

Comment: Although I DO see that you included it(adding child lists)!

Comment: NP - understanding someone else's context without all the code is often challenging.  It's why we often resort to building a [mre].  If the example code helped you on your way, then result.